# How to fix dependency problem about react native

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I start a new ReactNative project. When I use "react-native init newProject"
Give me those warn. How to fix that?

> npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer
>   maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version
>   of core-js@2. npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You
>   should commit this file.
>   npm WARN react-native@0.59.5 requires a peer
>   of react@16.8.3 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   fsevents@1.2.8 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING
>   OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.8: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

Comment: Well it's self explanatory, isn't it? `Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version.` `npm WARN react-native@0.59.5 requires a peer of react@16.8.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Answer (score 0):

Update package.json dependencies using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)